# Отображение поддоменов на одноимённые страницы

Tags: .htaccess

Какие записи необходимо внести в `.htaccess`, чтобы вместо .php страниц открывались поддомены с таким же названием?

Пример: `slovo-1.site.com` →  `site.com/slovo-1.php`.